# jquery each loop with ajax differently result

Tags: jquery

```
 $('.body').find('.entry').each(function () {
console.log('div found');
var that = $(this);
$.get('recommends').done(function(html) {
    that.append(html);
    console.log('appended');
});
});
```

in my chrome console

> (2) div found
>
> (2) appended

i want the result as below, any helps?

> div found
>
> appended
>
> div found
>
> appended

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: chrome console adds numbers in front of repeating outputs

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/DsLDt/ . It's usual behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think chrome group the message try to add index number to the maessages--but this is not the main reason

```
    var i= 0;
 $('.body').find('.entry').each(function () {
console.log('div found'+window.i);
var that = $(this);
$.get('recommends').done(function(html) {
    that.append(html);
    console.log('appended'+window.i);
});
});
```

also, it might be because of how ajax works it's async, 
the loop only asks the get call to start, while the done call back function executes when the ajax data is received

for example you've 2 children and you tell each one of them go grab me an orange 
you tell child one then child two, this what the foreach do
when each one of the children done it will say this your orange that what the done callback do

the foreach won'twait for the get to finish its work

Comment: its impossible to do as  

div found  
appended  
div found  
appended  ?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean by the comment.
i updated my answer